# What does free -m shows and how to explain it?

Tags: memory, hardware

My free -m

```
free -m
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           7971        1834        2878          79        3257        5713
Swap:          8179           0        8179
```

What is Mem and what is Swap?

Comment: There's a very fine manual page for this command, worthy of a read - https://linux.die.net/man/1/free

Comment: @steve and where in that fine manual page is the difference between swap and physical memory explained? Where is the meaning of "shared" or "buff/cache" explained? At best the man page has informative stubs that are clear to those of us who already know what shared memory is, it isn't very helpful to a new user.

Comment: To the question's credit, it is clearly written. It has a simple answer, so I submitted one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quoting from the `man` page:

> `free`  displays the total amount of free and used physical and swap
>   memory in the system

And your `-m` flag displays those amounts in megabytes.